# How to run bash script as root from user user?

Tags: bash, root, ubuntu-18.04

I have a couple of commands that need to be run from root

```
cd FolderName
sudo su
export VARIABLE_NAME=120
. install/setup.bash
ros2 run node node
```

I tried to create a script from these commands, but after the `sudo su` command, the script stops.
How can I run this set of commands under the root bash script?

Comment: Re: "after the `sudo su` command, the script stops": I doubt this. Rather, what's happening is that the `sudo su` command is running, waiting for you to type commands for it to run as root. If you were to type `exit`, the `sudo su` command would complete, and then the rest of the script would run (but as you, not as `root`).

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo su` wait for the user to enter `password` ?

Comment: @hansolo, I enter the password and after the script stops

Comment: No, it waits, just like @ruakh already told you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, run the script as root user like,

```
$ cat install.bash
#!/bin/bash

cd FolderName
export VARIABLE_NAME=120
. install/setup.bash
ros2 run node node
```

And then run as root,

```
$ su root install.bash
```

Comment: And can you somehow automatically specify a password in the script so that the user would not have to write it manually?

Comment: I think, you could use `expect` utility